# Number instead ringtone name

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-preferences

I want to get ringtone name. I use this code

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));
String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
```

And I get number (for example - 17090) not ringtone name. What's wrong?

Comment: This is probably filename. `getTitle` documentation says: _"Returns a human-presentable title for ringtone. Looks in media content provider. If not in either, uses the filename"_. Do you have correct Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem with recent versions of Android (4.4). There must be an issue with getTitle() and external storage since it works fine on internal storage. I also found that read access will also work. That may be less invasive for users.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I found answer. I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and it works now!

But why this permission is needed?

Comment: i seriously doubt that this is even remotely related

Comment: I tested it several times and without this permission it doesnt' works.